# Question about Delhi search (spoilers)

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-2

Question in spoiler tags below

> Searching Delhi reveals a companion, the Vector Control Technician. With that card in your hand, you do not get an exposure if you begin your turn in an infested city.
>  What if, with that companion in your hand, you begin your turn in an infested city that also has a plague cube?

Comment: The literal reading of the text and the answer that makes sense thematically are opposites; I'd give good odds the designers' intent follows the thematic answer but I don't have a source to back that up.

Comment: @BenjaminCosman that was my thought, too, hence my question here :)

Answer (score 3):

Play the text on the card to the letter. If the card says **infested**, it means **infested**.

Thematically the Vector Control Technician helps control the vectors that transmit diseases, such as rodents, birds, other animals, insects etc. They're like a specific pest exterminator, that only target the species that carry the disease. If you keep that in mind, it makes sense that they're so useful when the disease is being carried by humans.

If you can't find official errata that supports a widening of scope for a card, just play the card as is.

Comment: "Play the text on the card to the letter" -- to me, the card text is ambiguous.


Vector Control Technician says, "You do not get exposed when you begin your turn in an infested city if you have this card in your hand."


I take it that you read the card as meaning you do NOT get exposure if you start your turn in an infested city with a plague cube.



I'd have to double-check the exact phrasing of the "check for exposure" portion of the rulebook with the infested city rules sticker.

Comment: The rulebook section "Check for Exposure" says:
"If you start your turn in a location with 1 or more Plague cubes, gain an exposure.
Infested Cities:
Your character gets exposed if you begin your turn in a city marked with an infested symbol. (If the city has a Plague cube and is also infested, you get exposed only once, not twice.)

Comment: OK, since the rulebook combines the exposure from the two sources, I think Vector Control Technician also protects you from the plague cube.